# Copy element within copy element in Azure ARM deployment template to create multiple instances of a resource

Tags: azure, templates, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to create do a "nested for loop" in my Azure ARM deployment template via the [copy element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple) feature to create multiple instance of the same resource type ([Microsoft.Web/sites/hostnameBindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/hostnamebindings) in my case)

More specifically I'm trying to bind multiple hostnames to multiple apps (azure app service websites).

Is this possible? Or would I need to go down the [linked templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates) path?

Here is my attempt so far but I can't get it to work.

**parameters.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {    
    "appList": {
      "value": [
        { "appName": "app1", "hostNames": [ "app1.qqq.example.com", "app1.ttt.example.com" ] },
        { "appName": "app2", "hostNames": [ "app2.qqq.example.com" , "app2.ttt.example.com" ] },
        { "appName": "app3", "hostNames": [ "app3.qqq.example.com", "app3.ttt.example.com" ] }    
      ]
    }    
  }
}
```

**template.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {    
    "appList": { "type": "array"  }
  },  
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostnameBindings",
      "name": "parameters('appList')[copyIndex('webAppCopy')]/parameters('appList')[copyIndex('webAppCopy')].hostNames",
      "copy": [
        {
          "name": "webAppCopy",
          "count": "[length(parameters('appList'))]"
        }        
      ],
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]"
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Comment: Did you get this working, looks like your name property is wrong...

Comment: hi @bmoore-msft, I got it working the end by using a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with a different approach to solve this issue which results in slightly more duplicating names but gives me better flexiblity and readability

**parameters.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "webAppAzureNamePrefix": { "value": "mycompanyprefix-" },    
    "appList": { "value": [ "app1", "app2", "app3"]  },
    "hostBindings": {
      "metadata": { "description": "List of host bindings" },
      "value": [
        { "appName": "app1", "hostName": "app1.qqq.example.com" },
        { "appName": "app1", "hostName": "app1.ttt.example.com" },        
        { "appName": "app2", "hostName": "app2.qqq.example.com" },        
        { "appName": "app2", "hostName": "app2.ttt.example.com" },        
        { "appName": "app3", "hostName": "app3.qqq.example.com" },        
        { "appName": "app3", "hostName": "app3.ttt.example.com" },        
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**template.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "aspName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "metadata": { "description": "Name of App Service Plan" }
    },
    "aspSkuName": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [ "F1", "D1", "B1", "B2", "B3", "S1", "S2", "S3", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P4" ],
      "metadata": { "description": "Describes plan's pricing tier and capacity. Check details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/" }
    },
    "appList": { "type": "array" },
    "hostBindings": { "type": "array" },
    "webAppAzureNamePrefix": { "type": "string" }    
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('aspName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "sku": { "name": "[parameters('aspSkuName')]" },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('aspName')]",
        "numberOfWorkers": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppAzureNamePrefix'), parameters('appList')[copyIndex()])]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "webAppCopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('appList'))]"
      },
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "dependsOn": [ "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('aspName'))]" ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppAzureNamePrefix'), parameters('appList')[copyIndex()])]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('aspName'))]"
      },
      "resources": []
    },    
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostnameBindings",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppAzureNamePrefix'),parameters('hostBindings')[copyIndex()].appName, '/',parameters('hostBindings')[copyIndex()].hostName)]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "hostnameCopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('hostBindings'))]",
        "mode": "Serial",
        "batchSize": 1
      },
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "sslState": "SniEnabled",
        "thumbprint": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', parameters('certificateName'))).Thumbprint]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [ "webAppCopy" ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen anything in the docs about direct support for nested 
loops. But you could probably solve this with the [numeric functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-numeric) as follows:

1. define a template variable that is number-of-apps * number-of-addresses-per-app.  Let's call this variable bindingCount
2. Use bindingCount as the count for your "copy"
3. When constructing the resource name, use the div and mod functions to take copyIndex and turn it back into an "app index" and a "hostname" index.  I 
   think you'll have to do the math inline, in the formula that constructs the name.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRusk. I got this solution to work provided I had an equal amount of hostnames per app but if  not (e.g. app1 has 3 hostnames and app2 has 5 hostnames) then it breaks. Still trying to find a more "general" solution.

Comment: It might be worth trying to see if you can use the new (ish) "if" statement in a "condition" element to prevent it from trying to deploy on those iterations of the loop where copyIndex goes "off the end" of your hostnames array.  The catch is that that could get complex, and I'm not even sure that copyIndex is supported in "condition".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @John Rusk, but I opted for a more readable solution in the end.